# Write output into a file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, markdown

I have scraping function that gives me back content in form:

```
{'tagged': ['The Doors', 'Jim Morrison', 'Ray Manzarek', 'Robbie Krieger', 'John Densmore'], 'iframe': <iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eqgXGMAS__M?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" width="500"></iframe>, 'date': '2020-01-13'}
```

Desired output for me is to have it saved in markdown file in a format of:

```
---
title:  # this one is grabbed from url name
date: 2020-01-13
---
tagged: [[The Doors]], [[Jim Morrison]], [[Ray Manzarek]], [[Robbie Krieger]], [[John Densmore]]
<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eqgXGMAS__M?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" width="500"></iframe>
```

Before I had to add date I was using code as follows:

```
def write_posts(content, url, save_path):
    note_file_name = url.split('/')[4] + '.md'
    with open(save_path/note_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f"---\n"
                f"title: '{re.sub('[^0-9]', '', f.name)}'\n"
                f"---\n")
        for key, value in content.items():
            if type(value) is list:
                f.write(f"{key}: [[{']], [['.join(value)}]]")
            else:
                f.write(f"\n{value}")
    f.close()
```

But it won't work with date, it just adds it ad the bottom.
I tried changing last lines to:

```
        for key, value in content.items():
            if type(value) is list:
                f.write(f"{key}: [[{']], [['.join(value)}]]")
            elif type(key) == "iframe":
                    f.write(f"\n{value}")
                else:
                    f.close()
```

But it omits iframe and date enitrely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Luis's answer I figured out what I want / should do to make it work.
Now code outputs what I wanted it to do:

```
def write_posts(content, url, save_path):
    note_file_name = url.split('/')[4] + '.md'
    date = content.get('date')
    iframe = content.get('iframe')

    with open(save_path/note_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f"---\n"
                f"title: '{re.sub('[^0-9]', '', f.name)}'\n"
                f"date: {date}\n"
                f"---\n")
        for key, value in content.items():
            if type(value) is list:
                f.write(f"{key}: [[{']], [['.join(value)}]]")
            else:
                f.write(f"\n{iframe}")
                break
        f.close()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the iframe field of your string is not a valid JSON format.

I would recommend that if it is up to you to solve it.

However, the following function I think works fine receiving a json as a parameter.

```
def write_posts(content, url, save_path):
    note_file_name = url.split('/')[3] + '.md'


    title_line=f'title: {url}'
    date_line=f'date: {content["date"]}'
    separator='---'
    tagged_formated=", ".join([  str([[i]]) for i in content["tagged"]  ])
    tagged_line=f'tagged: {tagged_formated}'
    iframe_line=content["iframe"]
    text=title_line+"\n"+date_line+"\n"+separator+"\n"+tagged_line+"\n"+iframe_line

    with open(save_path+"/"+note_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text)
    f.close()


json={'tagged': ['The Doors', 'Jim Morrison', 'Ray Manzarek', 'Robbie Krieger', 'John Densmore'], 'iframe':'<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eqgXGMAS__M?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" width="500"></iframe>', 'date': '2020-01-13'}
url="https://www.hello.com/myhome.html"
path_dir= "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop" 
write_posts(json, url,path_dir)
```

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Got it! 
You helped me realize that I can, indeed, make it kinda more readable and thanks to this I have code that works as it should:

f.write(f"---\n"
                f"title: '{re.sub('[^0-9]', '', f.name)}'\n"
                f"date: {date}\n"
                f"---\n")
        for key, value in content.items():
            if type(value) is list:
                f.write(f"{key}: [[{']], [['.join(value)}]]")
            else:
                f.write(f"\n{iframe}")
                break
        f.close()

Thank you!